# iOS 11. UIScrollView in IPhone X shifts when trying to change the orientation of the interface

Tags: ios, ios11, iphone-x

I have two `UIViewController`. The first controller is used only in portrait orientation, and it contains the `UIScrollView`. The second controller is used only in the landscape orientation. When I try to open the second screen from the first one, the `UIScrollView` content is shifted to -44 by X on the first controller. This behavior exists only for the iPhone X. Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: We observed something similar. My first guess was to check "Automatically adjusts content insets", but that wasn't it. I had better luck when I realized that the top of the scroll view was constrained to the top layout guide, which is now relative to the safe content area. Try constraining the top directly to the top of the safe area.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For **Swift** developers:

```
 if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior.never
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
}
```

You don't need to handle this method if iOS is smaller than 11, anyway **iPhone X** starts with **iOS 11**.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is solved if I put:

```
scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentNever;
```